# Universal method in python for trying to parse a value to a chosen type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Is there a method in python that could allow me to parse a given value to a chosen type?

It might be a lib that works in a similar manner.

If there is not a method, how can I create something like it?

Example (parsing list[str] to list[int]):

```py
# could be a value of ANY type
value: list[str] = ['1', '2', '3']

# can be any other type
parse_to_type = list[int] 

# makes best effort to parse
parsed_value = universal_parser(value, parse_to_type) 

# parses or raises error 
# parsed_value = [1, 2, 3]
```

Bear in mind I don't won't a miracle function, something with parsing capabilities compared to Pydantic lib would be enough· Pydantic itself is able to parse from a list[str] to a list[int], but I was not able to locate inside the code how it does this for any type.

I know I can use something like `int(value)` or `float(value)` ( `annotation(value)` in general). But that won't **work for complex nested types** like: `list[int]`, `dict[str, str | int]`.

Comment: List and dict comprehensions are trivial to write and will solve this problem with existing type conversions.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I'm not talking about such a simple thing. I use lists and dict as a simple example, the problem I have has nothing to do with list or dicts. It is about a method that makes best effort to convert from a type to ANY other type.

Comment: But if you have such a function, you must specify the target type. In that case, you can just call the type directly, assuming it can do the conversion. Why add extra steps? Given you can create your own types and those types have no requirement to know how to convert other types, this seems impractical.

Comment: of course I must specify the target type, that's the whole point of the function. But this is dynamic, it is not decided when I write the code. In pratice (another example) I might have something like a specific set[list[str]], but I want to PARSE it to a set[list[int]].
The function would receive the variable, receive the type to parse to, and makes its best effort to parse the value to the type. This is really simple to understand. Pydantic does exactly that when validating/parsing the attributes of its model.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking... you *already* know about an example, the `pydantic` library. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I can dynamically create Pydantic models and I can use this to make use of it's parsing capabilities.

Bellow a simple implementation

```py
import typing
from pydantic import create_model


def universal_parser(value: typing.Any, annotation: type):
    """
    the return type is an instance of the annotation (don't know how to write it)
    """
    Parser = create_model('Parser', parsed=(annotation, ...))
    model = Parser(parsed=value)
    return model.parsed


print(universal_parser(['1', '2', '3'], list[int]))
```

This solves my problem since Pydantic's parsing capabilities is exactly what I desire. Though it leaves me wondering how Pydantic manages to parse such things. Bear in mind that this is not valid only for list[int], but any type Pydantic is able to parse, like datetime, float, dict and much more.

Comment: `annotation: type` is not actually correct, since you don't want to just accept types, (`list`, `int`, etc) but want to accept any valid annotation (e.g. `list[str]`, which returns a `typing.GenericAlias`

Comment: Oh great @juanpa.arrivillaga . I'm confused here, since
`isinstance(list[str], type)` and `isinstance(typing.GenericAlias, type)` both return true, it means they are both "types" so insn't types generic enought? like, it includes any valid annotation already?

Comment: Ah, maybe I'm confused! They must have added them as virtual subclasses then